# Annotate data points when x and y axis is text matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, annotate

I am trying to annotate data points on the plot shown below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Ha2.png)

I am unable to position the annotation text such that it is on the right side of the data point. Any hints on how this can be done?

```html
group1=df.groupby(['Year','Olympics','Medal','Hometown'])['Event'].count()
gr1_df=group1.reset_index()

bronze_data=gr1_df[gr1_df['Medal']=='Bronze']
gold_data=gr1_df[gr1_df['Medal']=='Gold']
silver_data=gr1_df[gr1_df['Medal']=='Silver']

plt.figure();
plt.style.use('seaborn');
plt.plot(bronze_data['Medal'],bronze_data['Hometown'],'*',label='Bronze Medals',alpha=0.5,markersize=10);
plt.plot(gold_data['Medal'],gold_data['Hometown'], 'o',label='Gold Medals',alpha=0.5,markersize=10);
plt.plot(silver_data['Medal'],silver_data['Hometown'],'^',label='Silver Medals',alpha=0.5,markersize=10);
plt.xlabel('Medal');
plt.ylabel('Hometown');
plt.legend();

count_data=gr1_df.groupby('Hometown')['Medal'].value_counts()
count_data.columns=['Counts']
df2=pd.DataFrame(count_data)
df2.columns=['Counts']
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)

ax=plt.gca()

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    ax.annotate(str(row['Counts']),xy=(row['Medal'],row['Hometown']),xytext=(row['Medal'],row['Hometown']),xycoords='data')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to play with the `xytext` and `textcoords` arguments of the [annotate](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) function. Here is an invocation which write the number on the right side of the point.

```py
ax.annotate(str(row['Counts']),xy=(row['Medal'],row['Hometown']), xytext=(5,-3),textcoords='offset points')
```

Kind

Comment: @SanjSam Do not hesitate to approve the answer, letting others know that the question is solved. Kind.